# jinja2 template for loop idention error in json file

Tags: jinja2

I'm trying to use a jinja2 template to render a json file. The structure is similar to:

```
"rows": [
  {% for product in products %}
  {
    "id": {{ loop.index }},
    "name": {{ product }},
    "available": true
  }{% if not loop.last %},
  {% else %}
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
],
[...]
```

The problem is that the output json is rendered as:

```
"rows": [
      {
    "id": {{ loop.index }},
    "name": {{ product }},
    "available": true
  },
      {
    "id": {{ loop.index }},
    "name": {{ product }},
    "available": true
  }
],
[...]
```

Note the bad indentation in the first **{** of each row. How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `-` to the Jinja2 enclosure to discard spaces in that direction:

```
{%- for product in products %}
```

Please read the documentation of [Whitespace Control](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#whitespace-control) for details.

Comment: I found that placing `#jinja2: lstrip_blocks: “True”` in the top of the template solves the problem.